# Regular in codim one scheme and DVR

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ be a noetherian integral (separated) scheme which is regular in codimension one. Let $Y$ be a prime divisor and let $\eta$ be the generic point of $Y.$ It seems I am missing something easy but why $\mathcal{O}_{X, \eta}$ is a DVR with the quotient field the function field of $X?$

And when it is said, $X$ is regular (non-singular) of codimension one, does it follow from the definition that the local ring of a codimension one closed subscheme is regular in general? (otherwise, the terminology doesn't make sense to me!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\mathcal{O}_{X,\eta}$ is a regular local $1$-dimensional noetherian domain. It is a Theorem in commutative algebra which says that this is precisely a DVR.

If $X$ is an arbitrary integral scheme and $x \in X$, then the quotient field of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is the function field of $X$. Namely, since this a local issue, we may assume $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ for some integral domain $A$, and just have to observe that $\mathrm{Quot}(A_{\mathfrak{p}}) = \mathrm{Quot}(A)$ for every prime $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A$.

As for the last question, you should look at the definitions. Nothing happens.

Comment: Dear Martin, I am aware of the theorem, but why it is of dimension $one?$

Comment: The dimension of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is the codimension of $\overline{\{x\}}$ in $X$ (which is also called the codimension of $x$).

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't aware of this important fact, thank you.