# Regular in codimension 1

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Apologies if this is an obvious question. I've really gotten my head tangled up in knots trying to approach it from the right angle, and I'm not getting anywhere - so I thought I'd ask.

A scheme is said to be regular in codimension 1 if every local ring $\mathcal{O}_x$ of $X$ of dimension one is regular.

Let $X$ be noetherian, integral, separated and regular in codimension 1.

Then every algebraic geometry reference ever says that if a subscheme of $X$ has codimension 1, the local ring of its generic point $\eta$ is of Krull dimension 1 $(*)$.

Nowhere seems to give this any thought, and I can't for the life of me see why it's true. Moreover, I cannot see how the dimension of the local ring of a point, that is, the dimension of a bunch of functions on the point, is in any way at all related to the dimension of the actual space it sits in.

If anyone could answer

1. Why $(*)$ is true.
2. Why these two things are actually related.

I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Edit: My commutative algebra has been quite wobbly in recent times, so the more anything of this nature is spelt out, very much the better!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If Y is a closed irreducible subspace of a scheme X, $y \in Y$ the generic point, then one has always

$$ \mathrm{codim}(Y,X) = \dim(\mathscr{O}_{X,y}).  $$

The closed irreducible subspaces of $X$ containing $y$ are in bijective correspondence with the closed irreducible subspaces of the local scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathscr{O}_{X,y})$, hence with the prime ideals of $\mathscr{O}_{X,y}$.  EGA is a reference that does have details for this (and most other things), see (EGA, IV_2, 5.1.2).

P.S. Happy belated birthday to Grothendieck!

Comment: Thanks for this. For future lost souls: a good reference for this is also Liu Qing's Algebraic geometry, which I discovered after I'd gotten most of the way with EGA.

Answer (score 0):

That was also my question which Martin answered it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221394/regular-in-codim-one-scheme-and-dvr)

**Hint**: Precisely, the dimension of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is the codimension of $\overline{\{x\}}$ in $X.$

Comment: You have just stated the fact Hock asked for a proof of.

Comment: Yes, indeed, since it's more instructive to prove this fact on his own. Refering to EGA, is excessive, of course.

Comment: You could give him a hint then, instead of just restating his question.  Why would referring to EGA be "excessive"?  He specifically expressed his frustration that every reference he looked at lacked a proof.

Comment: Dear Adeel, true, I added "hint."  I was also frustrated, since couldn't find the connection between these things. For me when I read the fact Martin gave me I started to think on my own and it was quite instructive. I believe at the moment of frustration the real development happens :)

Comment: Hello both. I ended up doing a combination of the two, and half-proving it myself, referring to EGA and trying to decode it with my terrible broken French. As Adeel says, I was extremely frustrated as to the general approach that everyone leaves it to everyone else, and I couldn't quite get a handle on the thing by myself. I now have a proof that I think by and large works. If it's the done thing, I could also post this as response, to aid any future lost souls. Would this be right thing to do?

Comment: @Hock future lost soul here, I was confused by this too, and not sure how to prove the accepted answer.  But it's been over a year, so I think you are excused from posting a proof ;-)

Comment: Ok well I have a proof in the case we need for the original question, although not sure about the full generality.  The affine case is easy in full generality.  For the reduction to affine case, given $Y$ has codimension 1 and $X$ irreducible it is easy to show that closed irreducible subsets of $X$ containing $y$ are in 1-1 correspondence with closed irreducible subsets of an affine open set $U$ containing $y$.

Comment: Maybe the proof of the reduction to affine case can be extended to the general case when $Y$ has arbitrary codimension, but I'm too tired tonight to do this.  Maybe I'll write something up later (or not, we'll see).